# Notificaciones locales cada X tiempo

Tags: android

Estoy desarrollando una app que te notifica 4 veces todos los días los recordatorios que tu hayas seleccionado.
La idea que tenía en mente era utilizar un servidor web para notificar mediante push cada X horas a los usuarios, pero sería más cómodo que el propio móvil añada unas "alarmas" y se notifique el mismo.

Es esto posible? Existe alguna funcionalidad parecida o debo usar las push?

Saludos y gracias

Comment: puedes agregar eventos a su calendario.

Comment: Usa la clase AlarmManager.